# Display path link like github folders in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to navigate same page with different parameters, here i have to display the page link like,

[image]

Need to show the title like this type. How to send title with click event with particular object.

Comment: Did you try anything or stuck anywhere? Because for this kind of things you have to do something on your own, you will not get any library for this. Try something with url may be split it and render texts of those and press of those text redirect to link.

Comment: Hi, i tried it my own. now its working fine. Thanks